# Cannot modify Medium claps with JS click event or POST request

Tags: javascript, http

Clicking on the clap button on a Medium article sends a POST to `https://medium.com/_/api/posts/226d4aba17f6/claps` where `226d4aba17f6` is the `post_id`. It sends with the following request headers and body

Headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
DNT: 1
Origin: https://brightthemag.com
Referer: https://brightthemag.com/the-next-trend-in-travel-is-dont-226d4aba17f6
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36
X-Client-Date: 1529809967158
X-Obvious-CID: web
X-XSRF-Token: XS3GqHxQelgDjr9T
```

Body:

```
clapIncrement:1
userId: <userid>
```

I'm trying to replicate this in Postman and I cannot for the life of me. I get a response every time stating 'user does not have access to modify claps.'

I cannot select the element and use javascript `.click()` either, nothing happens. I'm digging through Medium JS code right now with no luck, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is because medium website server might be using some cookie based authentication before sending response back .you cannot directly hit server with postman or other client directly by adding request body and headers only .you need those cookies to be added to your request and for one user there is only one authentication cookie. You will not saw this error " user doesn't have access " if cookie experiment is sucessful but you might get another error now that you will get on UI itself if you are trying to clap multiple times on same post . Hope that helps

Comment: dug into the chrome://net-internals/, found the cookie but still couldn't get it to work =/

Comment: I can see so many cookies such as __cfduid, lightstep_session_id,lightstep_session_id,uid,xsrf etc. under cookies section in chrome  . We cannot predict which cookie is medium is using for one time Authentication without getting code.

Comment: The request header from chome includes the __cfduid cookie though?